# Why does this CSV/MySQL import script timeout?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to import a CSV into a MySQL table and perform updates on the relevant rows. However, the script below is running very slowly and hits a timeout on the production server. I can get it to work on my localhost, but runs very slowly when I try to deploy. Any help would be appreciated.

```
if ( is_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ] ) ) {

    $csvFile = $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ];
    $query = "update tblworkoutdata3 
                set peakForce = ?, 
                    averageForce = ?, 
                    driveLength = ?, 
                    driveTime = ?, 
                    percentagePeak = ?, 
                    impulse = ?, 
                    work = ?, 
                    strokeSpeed = ?, 
                    forceCurvePoints = ? 
                where workoutid = ? 
                and personid = ? 
                and strokenumber = ?";

    $statement = $dbhandle->prepare( $query );

    if ( ( $handle = fopen( $csvFile, "r" ) ) !== FALSE ) {
        while ( ( $data = fgetcsv( $handle ) ) !== FALSE ) {
            $parameters = array( $data[8], $data[9], $data[10], 
                                $data[11], $data[12], $data[13], 
                                $data[14], $data[15], $data[16],
                                $workoutplanid, $athleteid, $data[0] );
            $statement->execute( $parameters );
        }
        fclose( $handle );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on the columns in your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: You could try reading the entire file into memory with [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)(be sure to use the right flags), then using `foreach` and [str_getcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to extract your data. This should be faster than reading line by line, but might not make much difference overall.

Comment: How many lines in the CSV? How many rows in the database? Which columns are indexed?

Comment: ___Which___ timeout is it hitting **specifically**?

Comment: No indexes on those columns.  I might try your suggestions. Seems strange that it can't handle it. It is about 700 updates to rows.

Comment: 'Connection Timeout'

Comment: 700 updates should take no time at all, so something here is a bit goofy

Comment: Agreed. So not sure what I am missing.

Comment: What is the EXACT error message you get in the error log

Comment: Request Timeout
This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

Comment: That does not look like a standard error message from PHP, MySQL, or Apache. It sounds like you're using a managed server of some sort, which probably has all sorts of throttling in place. How many rows get inserted before the timeout? Maybe you should have each process insert a small number of rows, and repeat as necessary until the whole file has been imported.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `LOAD DATA` to fetch the data.  That one step may be 10-100 times as fast.
2. Put the data into a temp table.
3. `UPDATE` (or IODKU) the real table from the temp table.